# Resize image with Python and keep EXIF and XMP metadata

Tags: python, image-processing, exif, xmp

Its been asked a lot of times how to resize an image and keep the existing exif data. I'm able to do that easily with PIL:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("image.jpeg")
exif = im.info['exif']
# process the image, for example resize:
im_resized = im.resize((1920, 1080), resample=PIL.Image.LANCZOS)
im_resized.save("resized.jpeg", quality=70, exif=exif)
```

I was wondering is there a way to **keep the XMP metadata** from the original image? There's a lot of GPS data in the XMP which I would love to keep in the resized version.

Comment: Hi @Dusan. Where you able to solve this somehow? I am at the moment at the same problem

Comment: @craaaft -  Yes I did. Take a look here: https://dusan-pacal.medium.com/how-i-managed-to-resize-an-image-and-keep-all-the-exif-and-xmp-metadata-using-python-fa68172ee479

Answer (score 0):

Not even the [successor Pillow can read XMP (and IPTC)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg). Also you're not really keeping anything - you create a whole new file and add a copy of the other EXIF data (including now potentially invalid information like width/height).

JFIF files aren't black magic - their [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) can be parsed rather easily; [XMP is most likely found in an APP1 segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform#Location_in_file_types) (just like EXIF). In rare cases it spans over multiple segments. You could first use PIL/Pillow to create your file and then modify it - inserting additional segments is trivial and needs no additional work.